# RadioButtons command to change the color of the text (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

*I am using tkinter for this project* After inputting some radio buttons, I have managed to change the color of the background of the windows itself when clicked. However, after adding another text widget, I want to change the color of that text when clicked these radio buttons. Would like to have your help in that simple command:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("WOOSAL")

def changeColourF(colour):
    root.configure(background =colour)
    choice1.configure(background =colour)
    choice2.configure(background =colour)
    choice3.configure(background =colour)
    choice4.configure(background =colour)

v =StringVar()
v.set("L")

choice1 =Radiobutton(root, text ="red", value =1, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("red"))
choice1.grid(row =0, column =0)

choice2 =Radiobutton(root, text ="blue", value =2, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("blue"))
choice2.grid(row =0, column =1)

choice3 =Radiobutton(root, text ="yellow", value =3, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("yellow"))
choice3.grid(row =0, column =2)

choice4 =Radiobutton(root, text ="green", value =4, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("green"))
choice4.grid(row =0, column =3)

w = Label(root, text="Hello Tkinter!")
w.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change text color with `fg` parameter.

```
def changeColourF(colour):
    root.configure(background=colour)
    choice1.configure(background=colour)
    choice2.configure(background=colour)
    choice3.configure(background=colour)
    choice4.configure(background=colour)
    w.configure(fg=colour)
```

[image]

Comment: is that going to change the color of w = Label() ?
I mean the text 'Hello Tkinter!'

Comment: Yeah. Check the update. Is that what you wanted? You need to call `w.configure()` to change label properties and `fg` is for foreground color (text color).

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate it, also deleted the background colour, so it now changes the colour of only the string! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, checked the update. Defenetely what I have wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Write a python GUI program that contains three Radio buttons for colors “Red”, “Green”, and “Blue”. Display selected color on a label.